# Angular 4 dynamic load templateURL

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a widget in `.net` framework, and I want to call same as it is in angular page, but I don't want to use iframe.

For this purpose I compile this page with razor engine and return plan HTML and write into html in angular project and I want to show this page in angular 4 application please help me any way to show this type ho html page show in my angular 4 application 
I want to show dynamic created html page into angular component [image]
this is my code where I try to create dynamic templateUrl

here I call this html template [image]
error on the type of build angular application moduleId: module.id is not found [image] 
and when I remove moduleId:module.id show warring [image]
how to solve this problem

Comment: Please, don't put images of texts. It is harder to read and to reproduce your issue...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {

    const template = '<span>generated on the fly: {{name}}</span>';

    const tmpCmp = Component({ template: template })(class {
    });
    const tmpModule = NgModule({ declarations: [tmpCmp] })(class {
    });

   this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(tmpModule)
      .then((factories) => {
        const f = factories.componentFactories[0];

        const cmpRef = this.vc.createComponent(f);

        cmpRef.instance.name = 'dynamic';
      }); 
  }
```